# Header issues with custom links

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, template, header, magento2.1.0

I have an issue. I put some custom links to my header. 
It looks like this for all my web-site pages now:
http://joxi.ru/52aRPqZu4kVjlA

However, for some reason on my home page those links are not showing.

What can be wrong there?

To configure my custom links I used this path:

```
/home/[my_theme]/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/
```

File: `logo.phtml`

But it looks like header for the main page is generated from some other place... Can't find it. Could anyone help me?

Web-site: https://tangs.com.au/

Comment: It sounds like you're (trying to) edit core files, you should be looking in the theme assets which override these files. It should be something like /magento2/app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml

Comment: Yes, this fie was missing so I created one but nothing is changed..

Comment: Any other ideas? Please help me someone...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by manually adding all links straight to logo.phtml file.

Path:
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header